# Is there an analytic expression for a number of elements inside a triangular matrix (with and without items on diagonal)

Tags: matrices

Is there an analytic expression for a number of items inside a triangular matrix (with and without items on diagonal)?

I tried to solve this with a combinatorial analysis using this "representation" of the problem:

( _, _ ) = ( n, m )

where:

- "n" is the matrix row index,
- "m" is the matrix column index. m = { 0, 1, 2, ... n }

but I don't have any further idea (I do not understand combinatorial analysis very well)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, I guess you simply want  the number of triangular matrix entries in an $N\times N$ matrix. .
So without the diagonal it is $N(N-1)/2$ and including  the diagonal it is $N(N+1)/2$.

Using your notation, matrix indices are usually indexed starting with 1, so you get the results via 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N \sum _{m=n+1}^N  1 = N(N-1)/2
$$
and
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N \sum _{m=n}^N 1 = N(N+1)/2
$$